# how to send aes key to server along with xml file

Tags: encryption

I'm currently developing a system to transmit data between client and server, and was wondering what the strength of the encryption I planned to use was.

My thought was to have a private/public RSA key pair and hand out the public key to each client (leaving the private key solely on the server). Each client would then generate their own AES key and RSA encrypt it. They would then AES encrypt their data and send the encrypted data and encrypted AES key to the server. The server would then decrypt the AES key using the private key, and then decrypt the data using the AES key.

now question is how to send aes key?

Comment: Most of the body of your question seems sensible. I would advise that you send a) An indicator that you're using version 1 of your encryption scheme, and b) An indicator of which public key (e.g. the thumbprint) has been used. That makes these things changeable later whilst still allowing your server to work out how to decrypt a specific message (so you don't have to upgrade server and clients simultaneously). But your final question either doesn't make sense or needs more detail adding. Send the key the same way you're sending the payload.

Comment: Thanks..i am sending as conn.setRequestProperty thorugh URLEncoder.encode however at server side m decoding it and getting extra character like ?

Comment: As I say, we need more details then - how are the client and server communicating *at all*? - you've not told us that, and there are plenty of ways for clients and servers to talk to each other. It sounds like you already have some code - and a particular issue - please edit your question, include (the relevant) parts of the code, share with us what your current issue is, and you're likely to get some answers.

Comment: I am communicating over httpUrlconnection.

Comment: Sounds like Java or Android? You haven't even included a tag in your question to indicate the platform(s) that you're working on. As I say, please *edit* your question and add these kind of details. (The edit link is just below the tags)

Comment: String encryptedAESfile=URLEncoder.encode( datastring);
        
         conn.setRequestProperty("encryptedString",encryptedAESfile);

Comment: its java only....i am able to get aes key data at server side but with additional characters '?'

Comment: I'll say it one more time. Please **edit** your question and add all of these details. You'll note that there's no code formatting in the comments - whereas in your question, you'll be able to add blocks of code (highlight the code and hit `{}` to mark it as code). If you do that and add the [tag:java] tag then we'll see beautiful syntax highlighted code.